# Real time database observer tools in Java/Scala

Tags: java, database, scala, real-time, observer-pattern

I'm looking for real time database observer framework or library in Scala or Java.

I don't want to use trigger or other solutions linked with a specific database.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you just would like to monitor the statements / results that are produced by your application, have a look at the documentation of the jdbc driver your are using. Most drivers have some logging options. If there are none, you could consider wrapping the jdbc-driver with a custom class, that delegates all calls to the real driver and insert your logging code there. Using AOP may also be a good choice to accomplish this.